# Bernoulli's Law

Tags: probability

Hi I have an exercise which we'd have to prove that Bernoulli's law is Probability law, the problem here is every time I try I can't get the result (which is 1), and when I check the correction I couldn't understand how he (my teacher) moved from the first line to the second, so if anyone could help me please (sorry for my English)

> Let $n\in \mathbb N, p\in [0,1]$. Then
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^n P(X= k) = \sum_{k=0}^n C_n^k\cdot p^k\cdot (1-p)^{n-k} = (p+1-p)^n = 1^n = 1.$$

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BgU9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p+q = 1$. Then $q = 1-p$, and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n P(X = k) &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}\\
&= (p+q)^n\tag 1\\
&= 1^n\\
&= 1
\end{align*}
where $(1)$ is true by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).
Note: $C_n^k = \binom{n}{k}.$

Comment: I just can't get why we make that sum of p + q ?

Comment: @WStudent I would like to answer but please be a little more specific. At what step/where?

Comment: The (p+q)^n
I mean why you took these 2 variables, it's the same passage that my teacher took, I mean for example why didn't you took (p + q + Ckn)^n ?

Comment: @WStudent, it is one thing if you say I don't understand and the other to give some arbitrary counterargument. Take a simple example p=0.3 and q = 0.7 and n = 2. and expand the formula such as this: ${2\choose0}(.3)^0(0.7)^2 + {2\choose1}(0.3)^1(0.7)^1+{2\choose2}(0.3)^2(0.7)^0$ and see what you get and then you will understand that it is merely $1=(0.3+0.7)^2 = 1^2 = 1$

Comment: @WStudent I see that you did not read the link. In addition to the comment above, the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) says that $$(p+q)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} p^kq^{n-k}.$$ Proofs can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Proofs).

Comment: Yes yes yes it's The multi-binomial theorem.. You're my hero, I'm really thankful guys especially Mr.Probablyme thank you a lot ^^

Comment: @WStudent No problem.

Answer (score 0):

He is using the binomial theorem, namely $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^{k}$$